# Dump subset of records in an OpenEdge database table in the ".d" file format

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I am looking for the easiest way to manually dump a subset of records in an OpenEdge database table in the Progress *".d"* file format.

The best way I can imagine is creating an extra test database with the identical schema as the source database, and then copying the subset of records over to the test database using FOR EACH and BUFFER-COPY statements.  Then just export the data from the test database using the *Dump Data and Definitions Table Contens (.d file )...* menu option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That seems like a lot of trouble.  If you can identify the subset of records in order to do the BUFFER-COPY than you should also be able to:

```
OUTPUT TO VALUE( "table.d" ).

FOR EACH table NO-LOCK WHERE someCondition:

  EXPORT table.

END.

OUTPUT CLOSE.
```

Which is, essentially, what the dictionary "dump data" .d file is less a few lines of administrivia at the bottom which can be safely omitted for most purposes.